# How to remove last part of my URL with .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Currently I have an URL that looks like :

> [www.mywebsite.com/confirm/ZChCQhXNJ5i](http://www.mywebsite.com/confirm/ZChCQhXNJ5i)

The last part of the URL is a random string. I want to remove it from my URL to get something like that

> [www.mywebsite.com/confirm](http://www.mywebsite.com/confirm/ZChCQhXNJ5i)

I've tried many things such as `RewriteRule ^(confirm)/.+$ /$1 [L,NC]` but I really don't understand the `.htaccess` syntax.

> Edit 1 - Here is my `.htaccess` file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
  RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

  RewriteRule ^(confirm)/.$ /$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

> Edit 2 - Your answers helped me, here is the solution I found :

```
RewriteRule ^(confirm)/(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Simply not working, I'm working locally with WampServer so maybe my .htaccess file isn't interpreted.

Comment: I've tried to write a rule to redirect the trafic to `https` and it's working so my .`htaccess` file is correctly interpreted. I've created a VirtualHost to access my website more easily. So right now the URL is : `project/confirm/ZChCQhXNJ5i` and that must change for `project/confirm`.

Comment: Is your mod_rewrite module enabled?

Comment: Yes, it is. I've found the solution to my problem now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using this RewriteRule?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/ZChCQhXNJ5i /$1 [L,R=301]
```

When I test this it works perfectly. See here: http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=33ae279c-7597-5935-8bf0-d389add54d0a

It successfully changes your URL to `www.mywebsite.com/confirm` using a permanent 301 redirection.

Comment: Your suggestion wasn't exactly what I looked for but it helped me to solve my issue. Thanks.